# dont show results if one match mySql

Tags: mysql

this question might be pretty simple but I'm stuck.
Data in my DB looks like this:

```
UserId | someId
1      |  2
1      |  3
```

I need to make query if user 1 has someId 2 then dont show me someId 3 neither, skip all records for that user

Comment: do you mean if any user has someid=2 then no need to select any records for that user ?

Comment: no, if for example userId 1 has someId 2 then dont show any results of userId 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name t 
  where not exists (
    select 1 from table_name t1
      where t.UserId = t1.UserId and t1.someId = 2
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve only one result for the user, you can Limit the result like below

```
SELECT * FROM new WHERE UserId = 1 Limit 1
```

or if you need to ignore other records which doesn't have someId = 2, you can do some thing like this

```
Select * from new Where UserId = 1 and someId = 2
```